# Selenium: aggregate Selenium By in presence_of_element_located()

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying out Selenium with Python. Is there a way to simplify code even more?

```
CLASS_NAME = "CLASS_NAME"
CSS_SELECTOR = "CSS_SELECTOR"
ID = "ID"
def check_element_type(element_type, element_string):
    if element_type == CLASS_NAME:
        return WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, element_string)))
    elif element_type == CSS_SELECTOR:
        return WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element_string)))
    elif element_type == ID:
        return WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_string)))
```

This is the concept goal but it does not work

```
def get_element(element_type, element_string):  
    return WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.element_type, element_string)))
```

It would throw an error if I explicitly import `selenium.webdriver.common.by` while having constant strings of the same name `CLASS_NAME = "CLASS_NAME"`, `CSS_SELECTOR = "CSS_SELECTOR"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `By` return string

```
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

in your method change `By.element_type` to `element_type`

```
def get_element(element_type, element_string):  
    return WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((element_type, element_string)))
```

and use it like

```
element = get_element("css selector", "div.myClass")
element = get_element("class name", "myClass")
element = get_element("xpath", "//div[@='myClass']")
```

or

```
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
element = get_element(CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myClass")
element = get_element(CLASS_NAME, "myClass")
```